# Why doesn't gradle exec work with scripts?

Tags: gradle

Is there any way to make gradle exec work like a shell exec?    ie - understand executable files in the path?

We have code that needs to work on windows and unix - and many many scripts that are obviously different on both machines.  While I can do a hack like this:

`npmCommand = Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS) ? 'npm.cmd' : '/usr/local/bin/npm'`

and then run that command - the paths for some scripts are not necessarily set in stone - and it's just horrible code.

Is there any way to fix the problem - ie extend the exec task to find executable files in the path and run them?

Comment: Of course, you can get standard $PATH value and process it using groovy. Btw, possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36273690/is-there-a-way-to-get-gradle-to-exec-a-command-line-in-path).

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
if (System.getProperty('os.name').toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT).contains('windows'))
{
    commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'commandGoesHere'
}
else
{
    commandLine 'sh', '-c', 'commandGoesHere'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**I'd love a better way** - but I made a simple function that I put in our common that you use like this:

```
exec {
     commandLine command("npm"), "install"
}
```

the function looks like this:

```
//
// find a command with this name in the path
//
String command( String name )
{
    def onWindows = (System.env.PATH==null);
    def pathBits = onWindows ? System.env.Path.split(";") : System.env.PATH.split(":");
    def isMatch = onWindows ? {path -> 
                for (String extension : System.env.PATHEXT.split(";"))
                {
                    File theFile = new File( path, name + extension);
                    if (theFile.exists())
                        return theFile;
                }
                return null;
        } : {path -> def file = new File(path,name);if (file.exists() && file.canExecute()) return file;return null;}

    def foundLocal = isMatch(file("."));
    if (foundLocal)
        return foundLocal;
    for (String pathBit : pathBits)
    {
        def found = isMatch(pathBit);
        if (found)
            return found;
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed to find " + name + " in the path")
}
```